# Manipulating Tuples in Python 3

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

I am having a rough time manipulating a tuple in Python 3.

The tuple is a single element consisting of a word joined to a number.

Having searched stack overflow and the web at large, i've had no luck attempting to split it.

`ftup = [('AT', 6)]`

I have attempted to

`list(ftup)` and `list.split`, but when using space to split my list, I keep all the brackets. I've attempted `map` but receive errors indicating type can't be mapped to str.

The eventual goal is to have the word printed as a string, and the number stored as an integer for comparing against another integer.

Comment: Have you tried `string, number = ftup[0]`?

Comment: you can split a tuple in two variables by just assigning it x1, x2 = ftup[0]

Comment: Is that intended to map 'string' and 'number' to ftup[0] when unpacking, or are you suggesting I create a tuple like that? If second, can't, based on user input

Comment: Javier's suggestion worked, thank you!

Comment: @ZackShapiro Just to be clear, the two proposed solutions in the comments are identical except for the names which are arbitrary. Zondo's comment is slightly more expressive which might aid human understanding but to python they're exactly the same.

Comment: Do you actually *want* to have a one-element list with a tuple in it? From your description it sounds like the list may be there by mistake (and you should fix that, rather than messing around it afterwards).